# How to copy different text to the clipboard (or selection) than what is displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I have an HTML table (in a single-page web application, so fancy JavaScript (including jQuery) is likely okay, and MSIE is not a target) in which one column has very long “keys” that contain underscore-separated words. In data preparation, I replace all underscores by `'_\u200B'` so the browser breaks words after them, and this works just fine.

Now, users might copy/paste from that table column and will inevitably end up with those invisible spaces. This affects both copy to the CLIPBOARD (the Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V style) and the PRIMARY selection (mark with the mouse, then hit middle-click to paste).

I’ve once seen a website where content different from what was showed was copied, but they didn’t publish the technique, and my web and SO recherche only showed methods to append additional content (source/copyright notice), not remove/replace content, therefore I’m asking for a solution to this.

Comment: https://clipboardjs.com/ allows you to target the text you want to copy. Is very easy to use, has good support and doesn't require flash.

Comment: @Novocaine that seems to trigger only on clicking a button. I do not wish to add a button, but to change the way the selected regular page text is copied. (Please do correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Yea, correct, that is based around a button click, but you could borrow from the functionality and use the click in the table column as the trigger to invoke this copy to clip board. If you wish to manipulate the actual value of what's been selected you could make use of the `Copy text from attribute` section, where you would have the text in the format you'd like the user to copy in that data attribute, and disable click dragging, so the user is forced to copy the nice version. Not a direct method, but one I think could work.

Comment: No, that doesn't help, I need to interfere with normal copy/paste.

Comment: Are you adding these invisible spaces just so long text will wrap, rather than taking up a load of space?

Comment: yes, so that long text will wrap at underscores (I know about CSS to make it wrap anywhere, but in the midst of words is still a no-go)